# How to render each function component UI (synchronous)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two UI function component and i wanna render them synchronous, I mean when the first component render finished,it will be delete into DOM then the second component will be render after that.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import Home from "./Home";
import Loading from "./Loading";
export default function Web() {
  const [beforeLoad, setBeforeLoad] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    async () => {
      await (new Promise<void>(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() =>{
          resolve(() => setBeforeLoad(true))
        }, 2500)
      }))
  }}, [])
    if(!beforeLoad) {
      return <div className="bg-gradient-to-r from-violet-500 to-fuchsia-500" style={{
        width: '100wh',
        height: '100vh',
        padding: 0,
        margin: 0,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        perspective: '500px'
      }}>
        <Loading />
      </div>
    } else if(beforeLoad) {
      return <Home />
    }
}
```

i used async await into hook but maybe i'm wrong.

as you can see, i wanna render Loading component first then Home component will be render after that.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I didn't quite get your question, can you explain with some code example?

Comment: reload your browser. pls. i just updated my question.

Comment: please take a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use async/await here, you can do it with JavaScript's setTimeout function

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Web() {
  const [beforeLoad, setBeforeLoad] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setBeforeLoad(true), 2500);
  }, [beforeLoad]);
  if (!beforeLoad) {
    return (
      <div
        className="bg-gradient-to-r from-violet-500 to-fuchsia-500"
        style={{
          width: "100wh",
          height: "100vh",
          padding: 0,
          margin: 0,
          overflow: "hidden",
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          perspective: "500px"
        }}
      >
        <h1>loading...</h1>
      </div>
    );
  } else if (beforeLoad) {
    return <h2>loading finished!</h2>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using timeout for this is really bad, set a boolean isLoading to true and switch it to false in the "then" portion of your promise when its resolved (you can do this with setting enum statuses instead of using boolean),
and if youre not fetching any data or no doing anything you can do a loading screen using css animations but why even show loading screen if theres no use for it?

Comment: i just wanna do something to make my product look better side UI, i am a fresher actually so i think u are right, thanks for your answer